# Why does a \timing always show faster times when run from within a script than on the terminal?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, benchmark

Let's say I have a very simple command like

```
SELECT count(*) FROM ( SELECT generate_series(1,100000) ) AS t;
```

If I open up a terminal and I run `\timing` and then the above query, I'll consitantly get massively slower times then if I run

```sh
$ psql --command '\timing' --command 'SELECT count(*) FROM ( SELECT generate_series(1,100000) ) AS t;'
```

It's not even close. Is there any explanation of this behavior and variance in `\timing`

### Output of Benchmark

When I run it in one go, I never get more than 5 ms

```
$ psql --command '\timing' --command 'SELECT count(*) FROM ( SELECT generate_series(1,100000) ) AS t;'

Timing is on.
 count  
--------
 100000
(1 row)

Time: 4.497 ms

$ psql --command '\timing' --command 'SELECT count(*) FROM ( SELECT generate_series(1,100000) ) AS t;'

Timing is on.
 count  
--------
 100000
(1 row)

Time: 4.437 ms
```

With the copy-paste into terminal I'm showing sometimes close to 20ms.

```
=# \timing
Timing is on.
ecarroll=# SELECT count(*) FROM ( SELECT generate_series(1,100000) ) AS t;
 count  
--------
 100000
(1 row)

Time: 9.500 ms

=# SELECT count(*) FROM ( SELECT generate_series(1,100000) ) AS t;
 count  
--------
 100000
(1 row)

Time: 19.017 ms
```

It doesn't seem to matter if I use Unix Domains Sockets or TCP.

### Psql version

psql (PostgreSQL) 13.4 (Debian 13.4-0+deb11u1)

Comment: Is the machine where you run this otherwise idle?

Comment: @jjanes yes, it is.

Comment: I can't reproduce that.  I think I would worry more about why one interactive execution was twice as slow as the other interactive one.

Comment: I can reproduce that with PostgreSQL 14.0 on Fedora Linux. You can use `perf` to see where the time is spent.

Answer (score 1):

(Not enough space to write a comment, so posting as an answer instead -- I'll change it when I hear back from the author)

Can you provide some more details about the "massively slower times" when using `psql`?  What version are you using?  In my tests, they look similar (3x in each method):

```
edb=# SELECT count(*) FROM ( SELECT generate_series(1,100000) ) AS t;
 count  
--------
 100000
(1 row)

Time: 13.328 ms
edb=# SELECT count(*) FROM ( SELECT generate_series(1,100000) ) AS t;
 count  
--------
 100000
(1 row)

Time: 12.400 ms
edb=# SELECT count(*) FROM ( SELECT generate_series(1,100000) ) AS t;
 count  
--------
 100000
(1 row)

Time: 12.242 ms
edb=# \q
[root@mdn /]# psql --command '\timing' --command 'SELECT count(*) FROM ( SELECT generate_series(1,100000) ) AS t;'
Timing is on.
 count  
--------
 100000
(1 row)

Time: 13.369 ms
[root@mdn /]# psql --command '\timing' --command 'SELECT count(*) FROM ( SELECT generate_series(1,100000) ) AS t;'
Timing is on.
 count  
--------
 100000
(1 row)

Time: 13.325 ms
[root@mdn /]# psql --command '\timing' --command 'SELECT count(*) FROM ( SELECT generate_series(1,100000) ) AS t;'
Timing is on.
 count  
--------
 100000
(1 row)

Time: 13.257 ms
```

Comment: updated answer with output of benchmarks and version.